# CiviCRM admin functions lost after installing Polylang

Tags: wordpress

CiviCRM Version 4.5
WordPress Version 4.3.1

Everything was fine until we installed Polylang to make our site bilingual. Now, many man-hours later, we find that when accessing CiviCRM functions we get:

"You do not have permission to execute this url."

Unfortunately, the Polylang documentation states: "when
Polylang is de-activated, every URL loses the language information and thus all external links are broken".

We have found:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32347.0

but do not know if it is a related problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given in the forum post?

Comment: The forum post suggests making modifications to 'wordpress.php', a file that does not appear to exist in my installation.

Comment: They're talking about the file at '/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php'